# imageview web imageresource

Tags: android, image

I want to read image from web

ex. http://www.abc.com/image1.jpg

and dynamic set to imageview component. how can i do it? any good tutorial ??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what dynamic means here, but are you looking for [ImageView.setImageURI](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageURI(android.net.Uri))?

Comment: yes you are right, i am looking for good example of ImageView.setImageURI